# Woocommerce order item meta special characters encoding

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When creating a new order, I add some metadata to some order items. I do it in this way

```
wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, '_myData', array(
    'text' => array('Gött mos')
))
```

However, when I get the item meta back using `wc_get_order_item_meta` the string `Gött mos` is replaced with the string `G00f6tt mos`. After looking it up a little bit, it seems like the character `ö` is replaced with some kind of unicode representation of the same character. How do I get the text back without it being "encoded"?

EDIT:

I just discovered that wc_add_order_item_meta is a plain proxy of Wordpress's function `add_postmeta`, which makes this a problem with a Wordpress functions rather than Woocommerce.